# SyncFramework Provisioning Exception

Tags: exception, azure, provisioning, microsoft-sync-framework

I am getting a DbPartialllyProvisionedException when i try provisioning the microsoft azure scope. It is returning an error "Invalid column name 'ISQLHELPERCACHEDPRIMARYCLIENTNAME'." And I am not sure why, since it was working previously. A few changes were made to the ce database, ie more tables were added, but that was it. If anyone could help it would be much appreciated.

Code for the provisioning:

```
*

SqlCeConnection sqlCEConnProv = new SqlCeConnection(SQLCEConnectionString);
                sqlCEConnProv.Open();
                SqlCeCommand cmd = sqlCEConnProv.CreateCommand();
                cmd.CommandText = "select table_name from information_schema.tables where TABLE_TYPE <> 'VIEW' AND TABLE_NAME NOT LIKE '__sys%'";
                SqlCeDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                List<string> tableNames = new System.Collections.Generic.List<string>();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    tableNames.Add(reader.GetString(0));
                }
                SqlConnection sqlAzureConnProv = new SqlConnection(SQLAzureConnectionString);
                DbSyncScopeDescription myScope = new DbSyncScopeDescription(scopeName);
                foreach (string tableName in tableNames)
                {
                    DbSyncTableDescription Customer = SqlCeSyncDescriptionBuilder.GetDescriptionForTable(tableName, sqlCEConnProv);
                    myScope.Tables.Add(Customer);
                }
                // Setup SQL Server for sync
                SqlCeSyncScopeProvisioning sqlServerProv = new SqlCeSyncScopeProvisioning(sqlCEConnProv, myScope);
                sqlServerProv.ObjectPrefix = syncPrefix;
                if (!sqlServerProv.ScopeExists(scopeName))
                    // Apply the scope provisioning.
                    sqlServerProv.Apply();
                // Setup SQL Database for sync
                SqlSyncScopeProvisioning sqlAzureProv = new SqlSyncScopeProvisioning(sqlAzureConnProv, myScope);
                sqlAzureProv.ObjectPrefix = syncPrefix;
                if (!sqlAzureProv.ScopeExists(scopeName))
                {
                    // Apply the scope provisioning.
                    //string script = sqlAzureProv.Script();  // debugging
                    sqlAzureProv.Apply();
                }
                sqlCEConnProv.Close();
                sqlAzureConnProv.Close();
```

*

Comment: can you post the provisioning code? or better, enable Sync Fx tracing and post the trace

Comment: I added the code to the post @JuneT

Comment: can you confirm that the column actually exist on the table? if the table already exists during provisioning, SyncFx will not add a column to it.

Comment: it does not exist in the table

Comment: your sync scope definition is coming from your SQLCE DB, if a column exists in your client but not on a the server, SyncFx will not add it. Sync Fx dont do schema syncs.